# svn 1.7.8 database is locked, cannot release

Tags: svn

when I run:

```
svn cleanup
```

I get the error message:

```
svn: E200033: database is locked, executing statement 'RELEASE   s0'
```

or any other command to change DB, e.g. `commit`, `update` etc.

This is on linux server, the directory is nfs.

I can checkout another version and copy my changes, but it is a hassle and I think this error will come back.

how do I fix this on a working directory, and is there a way to prevent it.

p.s. there are no processes currently running, maybe eclipse crashed in the middle of some action.

Comment: Are you using the file or berkeley DB storage backend?

Comment: @CraigRinger irrelevant; this is a client (working copy) error, which uses SQLite combined with the filesystem.

Comment: @alroc Good point. Zamir, is the *working directory* on NFS? Because SQLite + NFS = potential for kaboom.

Comment: I was under the impression it is Postgre, I guess it is SQLLite, I do use NFS, so there is no remedy?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This helped me solve the problem (subversion 1.7.10):

```
$ cd /my/repository/.svn
$ mv wc.db wc.db.old
$ sqlite3 wc.db.old
sqlite> .backup main wc.db
sqlite> .exit
```

After making sure it works, you can remove wc.db.old.

See also: http://technosophos.com/content/sqlite-database-locked-error-and-unlocking-database

Comment: In my case, it did not help. I had to stop `rcp.statd` on the target machine to make NFS locking work again.

Comment: mv command fails for me. If that was the case I could mv the original working copy directory. not the .svn one.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Just wanted to add that "svn cleanup" is still required post this operation

Answer (score 68):

In windows I killed the process `TSVNCache.exe` and that helped me.

Comment: additionally closed intelliJ + followed @VictorFernandez procedure

Comment: I killed this but db was still locked.

Comment: I had to kill **explorer.exe** as well, as I found it was locking .svn/wc.db. Used this tool in windows. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Killing `TSVNCache.exe` helped for me, but did not completely resolve (work-around) the issue. `svn cleanup` from the command line finished the job (but not before killing the process).

Answer (score 7):

Following steps worked for me.

1. Close all the files open for that repo in the other notepads/eclipse
2. run svn cleanup
3. run svn up.

Answer (score 6):

may be sometimes svn keep running in the IDE(if svn configured in IDE) and locks the svn files. close your IDE and then perform clean up.
or use simple way restart your pc and then perform cleanup.

Comment: Pro tip: terminal-based text editors also seem to count...including any that happen to be running in 'screen' sessions...including detached ones! I banged my head on this one for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
svn resolved -R .
```

If you still see issues, go one level up and execute the same command.

Comment: When I do that I get "svn: warning: W200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked, executing statement 'PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=1;PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA recursive_triggers=ON;PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL;PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE;'"

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu system try following commands.

ps -efa | grep 'svn'

7792 15593  0 14:10 pts/3    00:00:03 svn status

it will list down all running processes of SVN.
Kill svn process that is currently running.

Kill -9 7792

Try after kill process it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tagging and releasing through NetBeans

Please change the path to the installed svn in  your IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my issue by closing IDE like netbeans/sublime.

Close IDE and again do pull request.

Please try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me on a Windows system, I had to restart the SVN service to clear the lock on the database and then run a clean-up on the branch and all worked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this problem for me was that I re-installed TortoiseSVN version 1.9.2.  In the process of doing this I had to shut down the processes for Explorer, Eclipse (using the svn workspace), TortoiseSVN, SQL Dev, Notepad++...

So maybe it was something with restarting these processes that fixed the problem, or reinstalling TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

Updated visual code IDE block this svn update. so close the vs code. and its work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using netbean windows version. I try to right click the root folder->subversion->working copy->cleanup. It doesn't work. I saw above command "svn cleanup" but the in Windows, don't have this command line. What I do I download the tortoisesvn from https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html, install it with the "Commandline client tools" during installation. After installed, you can run "svn clean" in your root folder (make sure your netbean ide is closed), then everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble here on windows 10.

Working in selenium tests, when I try to commit my changes, the SNV shows the error: Database is locked.

I have executed svn cleanup and still no working.

So, I opened the windows task manager (ctrl + shift + esc) and I saw some chromedriver.exe process still running. I killed all of them and executed svn cleanup again and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

I kill TortoiseProc.exe process in windows